# Como puedo hacer operaciones de 2 combobox y que se refleje en una columna del datagridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que estoy haciendo es venta de boletas y de un combobox es el destino el otro origen y en el dgv tiene q salir el valor dependiendo del numero de asientos q escoga el usuario en otro cb asientos

```
namespace datagridview
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAgr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvBoleto.Rows.Add("", txtNom.Text, cbOri.Text, cbDes.Text, cbAsi.Text);           
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //combobox origen
            cbOri.Items.Add("Quito");
            cbOri.Items.Add("Guayaquil");
            cbOri.Items.Add("Cuenca");

            //combobox destino
            cbDes.Items.Add("Quito");
            cbDes.Items.Add("Guayaquil");
            cbDes.Items.Add("Cuenca");

            //combobox asiento
            cbAsi.Items.Add("1");
            cbAsi.Items.Add("2");
            cbAsi.Items.Add("3");
            cbAsi.Items.Add("4");
            cbAsi.Items.Add("5");
        }

        private void dgvBoleto_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            this.dgvBoleto.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
        }

        private void btnSal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult opcion;
            opcion = MessageBox.Show("Realmente desea Salir de la Aplicacion ?", "SALIR DEL PROGRAMA", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            
            if (opcion == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si comprendí bien tu problema, pero creo que buscas que el DataGridView se llene con los valores seleccionados, lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma, te dejo todo el código que utilice para este pequeño ejemplo:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cargarComboOrigen();// solo carga el combo de origen y dejo la responsabilidad de cargar los otros combos al combo anterior
        }

        private void cargarComboOrigen()
        {
            cbo_origen.Items.Add("Quito");
            cbo_origen.Items.Add("Guayaquil");
            cbo_origen.Items.Add("Cuenca");
        }
        private void cargarComboDestino()
        {
            cbo_destino.Items.Add("Quito");
            cbo_destino.Items.Add("Guayaquil");
            cbo_destino.Items.Add("Cuenca");
        }
        private void cargarComboAsientos()
        {
            cbo_asiento.Items.Add("1");
            cbo_asiento.Items.Add("2");
            cbo_asiento.Items.Add("3");
            cbo_asiento.Items.Add("4");
            cbo_asiento.Items.Add("5");
        }

        private void cbo_origen_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//evento que se activa cuando hay un cambio en el index del combobox
        {
            if (cbo_origen.SelectedIndex != -1) // para validar que seleccino algo y asi cargar el combo de destino
                cargarComboDestino();
        }

        private void cbo_destino_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbo_destino.SelectedIndex != -1)
                cargarComboAsientos();
        }

        private void cbo_asiento_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbo_destino.SelectedIndex != -1 && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cbo_destino.Text)) // valido que el combo se alla desplegado y seleccionado algo
                dgv_venta.Rows.Add(new object[] { cbo_origen.Text, cbo_destino.Text, cbo_asiento.Text, (Convert.ToInt32(cbo_asiento.Text) * 1000) });
        }
```

y esto es lo que se vería en un form:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si muchas gracias ya le entendi tenia que convertir para pasarlo al dgv